# Is exporting nodejs module correct?

Tags: node.js

My goal is to display a website which gives users a menu, then from there they click on what functionality they want to run, and then node runs a command on the back end on a ubuntu server using "exec" then displaying the results to the webpage.
So far I have two files, a nodejs file and an html page

```
var http = require('http'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec,
    fs = require('fs')  ;


function onRequest(req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
   fs.readFile('form.html', function(err, data){
                if(err)
                        {
                        res.write("err.message");
                        }
                                else
                                {
                            res.write(data);
                            res.end();
                                }
         });


}

var server = http.createServer(onRequest);
server.listen(80, '0.0.0.0');

console.log("Server Running");
```

then the form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
Please select from the following options:
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="apps">Insert all Apps belonging to a group</option>
  <option value="groups">Insert groups in databse</option>
  <option value="database">Refresh database group table</option>
  <option value="another">Add all app from one group to another</option>
  <option value="id">Get Group ID</option>
  <option value="user">Get User ID</option>
  <option value="list">Get list of all apps</option>
</select>
</form>

<p>Click the button to change the selected fruit to banana.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {

  if(document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "apps")
    {
     //do something and display results to webpage
     }
    else
    {
    //display error
    }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is, is this the right way of carrying out this task? and if so,should I export the onRequest function which would then allow me to display what I want to the webpage with res.write ?